# How to display image when it is uploaded in ASP.NET mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I wont to display or preview image when its uploaded

my code is here :

Html.Label("Browse File", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

```
              </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.Label("Logo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <img src="FileUpload1" alt="Image" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved Thant's
here my code

```
 @Html.Label("Browse File", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" class="form-control"  onchange="document.getElementById('logoImage').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">

    <pre>
            `enter code here`        &lt;/div&gt;
                     &lt;div class="col-sm-4"&gt;
                         @Html.Label("Logo Image", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                         &lt;img id="logoImage" src="FileUpload1" alt="Logo Image" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px ;margin-top:20px; margin-left:120px;" /&gt;


      &lt;/div
```

>